# BeautifulSoup get to list

Tags: python, split, beautifulsoup

I am having difficulty in figuring out how to place BeautifulSoup return string into a list.

Everything I've read says that to put a comma delimited string in a list I just have to do something like:

```
my_list = my_string.split(",")
```

The problem is that I retrieve something that looks like this (see code below):

```
"EURUSD=X",1.1205,"6/24/2015","10:06pm"
```

If I try to split it, I get a `NoneType` error.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?
e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=EURUSD=X')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

print (soup)
soup.split(",")
```

gives me:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup is for parsing HTML. why are you using it on CSV data?

Answer (score 0):

As [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) says: `split` is a mothod for `strings`. Be sure `soup` is a string, you could print

```
type(soup)
```

to find out which type it is, if it is not a string, that's the error, and you probably need process a little more with beautifulSoup to get the string you want.

If `r.text` contains all what you want, try:

```
str(soup(r.text))
```

Comment: good catch. it's listed as "<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>"  type. I'll have to try & figure out how to convert to a string easily.  Problem looks like it might be the double quotes and the non-quoted number.

Comment: and the answer is just assign it using str() . Great stuff, python, very similar to other languages...           a=str(soup)